# SQL Server Closing Stock values to opening stock of Next month

Tags: sql-server

I have a stock table contains three columns: Month, Year and Closing Stock like this:

```
Month   Year      CLosingstock
------------------------------
Jan     2017          10
Feb     2017          20
Mar     2017          30
Dec     2017          40
Jan     2018          50
Feb     2018          60
```

I want to create the new column of Opening stock and the jan 2017 values(10) should be a opening stock to Feb 2017.So How i place the values and other months opening stock to closing stock of next month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the window function `LAG()`. I am assuming your `Month` is a integer and not string

```
select *, OpeningStock = LAG(ClosingStock) OVER (ORDER BY Year, Month)
from   YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks for reply  i tried but month columns was not  asc ordered.  I give 

select Month,Year,ClosingStock, OpeningStock = LAG(ClosingStock) OVER (ORDER BY  Month,Year Asc)  
from   tblTest
I need month columns as Jan........to  Dec  this order, But my columns was colapsed

Comment: is your month column string or integer ?

Comment: also if you use `LAG()`, it should be `ORDER BY Year, Month` and not `Month, year Asc`. Also take note  that you should use a Month in int and not string

Comment: surely you must have a date / datetime column in your table. Or else how do you `ORDER BY`  the month in JAN, FEB, MAR